# onSelectionChange is corrupted after sharing file

Tags: google-apps-script

In a google sheets, a script using onSelectionChange that when the sheet 'Sheet 3' is selected, it will go out to sheet 'Sheet 2' and write something in cell E1. This works until you share it or change some of the code. Then it only does part of the work: it writes on the sheet 'Sheet 2! E1' but not exit from 'Sheet 3' and not shows 'Sheet 2'. If you close the file and re-enter it is not fixed (I usually have to do this to get it to work the first time I use onSelectionChange on a file). BUT if you create a copy of the changed file, that copy used to works fine together with the changes. What should I do so that onSelectionChange is not broken?

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
  const sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getSheetName();
  if(sheetName=='Sheet 3'){
    change1();
  }
}

function change1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet 2'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('You are not Allowed');
};
```

Comment: The basic problem is that onSelectionChange is a simple trigger and it cannot perform operations that require permission like gettiing user emails.  There are no installable triggers for this so there is no work around.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Cooper! I change the code as you can see but unfortunately the error persist. It write in 'Sheet 2!E1' but don't change view to the 'Sheet 2' nor active cell E1. It works me in a first moment but it becomes corrupted when I write something new in function change1 and it is not repair even if I delete changes.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

- When you run a function Apps Script automatically provides it the necessary scopes.
- You can check the scopes your script is using by going on `File->Project-> Properties` in the Legacy Editor or `Overview-> Project OAuth Scopes` inthe new editor - see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#viewing_scopes)
- If you remove the request that needs a certain scope from your code and save the script - Apps Script will not automatically remove the redundant scopes
- If your script contains scopes that  cannot be used with a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) - you trigger will result in an error

**Solution:**

- Remove redundant scopes by setting the required scopes manually in the manifest - as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)

Note:

- Be careful with sheet names - `Sheet 3` is not the same as `Sheet3`.
- If your script execution errors - view the script executions to see the exact error message for debugging.

**UPDATE 02/02/21**

As of now, there is a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/178615259) with `onSelectionChange`. If you are affected, give it a `star` on Google's Issue Tracker to increase visibility.

Comment: In Project OAuth Scopes there are this:
See, edit, create, and delete your spreadsheets in Google Drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
View your email address https://.../auth/userinfo.email
and appsscript.json don't have any "oauthScopes": [

...Anyway, I don't have any email included in the onSelectionChange code (it's in another function). On the other hand, I have created a new equal code for onEdit and for onSlectionChange and it works fine only for onEdit. That is, with onEdit it changes the sheet and writes but with onSelectionChange it only writes. What am I missing?

Comment: There is currently a new [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/178615259) with the`onSelectionChange` trigger. This is probably the reason for your issue.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I have added a star and also commented the bug on Google's Issue Tracker. Thanks ziganotschka!!